# Text View Above overrides Text View below it

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a textView in a list item with another text view below it.
I am facing one problem again and again that when text increases . text view above overrides my text view below or text view below comes on top of text view above.

My XML in RelativeLayout is  :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tp_activity_wise_badge_fragment_each_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tp_White"
    android:minHeight="60dp">        
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:text="Loading Title..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#737574"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:background="@color/tp_White"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#737574"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading Subtitle..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/tp_inactive_channel_text_color"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textview1" />
```

i know this is very basic problem but this is very undefined for me and i am not able to position this views such that they dont cut each other.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: put screenshot first

Comment: where you want subtitle?

Comment: Have you set a max height for your list view items? If so then it would make sense that things would overlap. It sounds like they are running out of room.

Comment: i want My title to be center-verticle

and subtitle below it.

but when text enters second line..subtitle comes over title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `layout_alignParentRight` in your code.

its not proper way you set margin to set view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tp_activity_wise_badge_fragment_each_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tp_White"
    android:minHeight="60dp">        
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Loading Title..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#737574"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"

        android:background="@color/tp_White"

        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Loading..."

        android:textColor="#737574"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading Subtitle..."

        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview1"
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use LinearLayout (just copy and paste it)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tp_activity_wise_badge_fragment_each_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="25dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading Title..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#737574"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#737574"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading Subtitle..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve by writing `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textview1"` and at same time `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview1"`.

Instead you can try `android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"` this will align your `textview` vertically.